# in a subselect query how do i refer to the id of the top level select statement?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to automate my table population for testing purposes.

I needed to edit some columns from a certain table but I must make sure that the values I put in that certain column does not simply come out of randomness.

So the values actually comes from another table on a certain condition.

How can I do that? Just like this code:

```
update table_one set `some_id`=(select some_id from another_table where another_table.primary_id=table_one.primary_id order by rand() limit 1)
```

It's something like my condition for the Subselect query. It should match the `id` of the current row I am updating.
I really forgot my SQL now. Thanks for the answers though.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there - all you need to do is qualify the column you're selecting in the subquery, so you know it comes from the correct table:

```
update table_one
set some_id=(
    select another_table.some_id
    from another_table
    where another_table.primary_id=table_one.primary_id
    order by rand()
    limit 1
)
```